# What exactly does future=True do in sqlalchemy's create_engine() function?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm reading through the [SQLAlchemy 1.4 / 2.0 tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/). In it, they suggest creating an engine via

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:", echo=True, future=True)
```

Digging into the docs for `create_engine()` it says,

> :param future: Use the 2.0 style :class:`_future.Engine` and
> :class:`_future.Connection` API.

What exactly does this mean? What functions or classes won't work if I exclude `future=True`? (Note that I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.4.26)

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-to-2-0-step-four-use-the-future-flag-on-engine

Answer (score 3):

The "future" flag is a mechanism to allow a seamless shift from prior versions of SQLAlchemy to the new v2.0. The interim version (v1.4) has a foot on each side of the transition. Here is the note from the 1.4 tutorial:

> **A Note on the Future**
>
> This tutorial describes a new API that’s released in SQLAlchemy 1.4
> known as 2.0 style. The purpose of the 2.0-style API is to provide
> forwards compatibility with SQLAlchemy 2.0, which is planned as the
> next generation of SQLAlchemy.
>
> In order to provide the full 2.0 API, a new flag called future will be
> used, which will be seen as the tutorial describes the Engine and
> Session objects. These flags fully enable 2.0-compatibility mode and
> allow the code in the tutorial to proceed fully. When using the future
> flag with the create_engine() function, the object returned is a
> subclass of sqlalchemy.engine.Engine described as
> sqlalchemy.future.Engine. This tutorial will be referring to
> sqlalchemy.future.Engine.

See the site for more information: [SQLAlchemy 1.4 Tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/index.html)